# MySQL Query Selecting records from a database where a value equals one of two different things

Tags: php, mysql

I have to get records from my MySQL DB where:

```
sentto = "$username"
```

OR

```
sentto = "everyone"
```

How would I put this in a MySQL query? I tried a few things, but they don't seem to be working:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * 
             FROM pmessages 
             WHERE status='unread' 
                 AND sentto='$username' || sentto='everyone'");

mysql_query("SELECT * 
             FROM pmessages 
             WHERE status='unread' 
             AND sentto='$username' 
                 AND sentto='everyone'");
```

I seem to be stumped, if anyone knows how to do this the right way please let me know. This is a new scenario for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM pmmessages 
WHERE sentto = '$username' 
    OR sentto = 'everyone'
```

**Edit** Chris, based on your new query of:

```
SELECT * 
FROM pmessages 
WHERE status='unread' 
    AND sentto='$username' 
OR sentto='everyone'
```

You need to modify it so that your AND stands alone (it is conflicting with your OR).

Rewrite it to this

```
SELECT * 
FROM pmessages 
WHERE status='unread' 
    AND 
        (sentto='$username' 
            OR sentto='everyone' )
```

Comment: Yeah, I used that but it is returning one more record than it should be. Here is my current string: mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pmessages WHERE status='unread' AND sentto='$username' OR sentto='everyone' ");

Comment: Chris, it may do you well to find some information on SQL and the logic behind evaluating Boolean Operators like AND, NOT, and OR. You will find that if you don't group them together properly, it will evaluate incorrectly and you won't get the results you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Taking the detail from one of your comments into account - use the " `OR` " keyword and parentheses to make sure that the right conditions are combined.

```
SELECT * FROM pmessages WHERE
   status = 'unread'
    AND
  (sentto = ? OR sentto = 'everyone')
```

Your problem was never with the `OR`, though, it was actually the `AND` precedence and lack of parentheses.  The very significant detail that you completely omitted from your question was the additional test for "`status = unread`".

Note the use of `?` above - you should *really*, *really* use prepared statements whenever combining MySQL and PHP, i.e.:

```
$sql = "..." # as above
$sth = $db->prepare($sql);
$res = $sth->execute($username);
while ($row = $sth->fetchrow()) {
    ...
}
```

(or the `mysqli` equivalent)

Answer (score 2):

As it's the same column you're testing, I would use the `IN` keyword:

```
SELECT * 
FROM pmessages 
WHERE status='unread' 
AND sentto IN ('everyone', '$username');
```

Answer (score 0):

The word OR is what you're looking for:

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pmessages WHERE sentto='$username' OR sentto='everyone'");

Comment: Yeah, I used that but it is returning one more record than it should be. Here is my current string:

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pmessages WHERE status='unread' AND sentto='$username' OR sentto='everyone' ");

Comment: enclose the two 'sentto' tests in parentheses.  currently it's treated as "(status = 'unread' AND sentto = ...') OR sentto = 'everyone'"

Answer (score 0):

is everyone an actual value or do you want to return all results?

if you want to return all results set up something like this

```
if (@sentto is null)
begin

     set @sendto='%'

end

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pmessages WHERE sentto='$username'")
```